# How to show whitespace character in Sourcetree Diff

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I wanted to see the whitespace characters in diff section of SourceTree.

By selecting `Show Whitespaces` from options I can see the git diff due to spaces but I am not able to see the space characters.

Is there any way to see whitespace characters ( just like in IDE ) in diff section of SourceTree ?

Is there any way to see tab characters ( just like in IDE ) in diff section of SourceTree ?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that right now. You'll have to submit a feature request to Atlassian (there is an [existing one for SourceTree-Mac](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-2408) but it seems it's set to a low-priority). If you're intent on using SourceTree, you can workaround this by configuring an external diff tool and opening the diff there instead (though that kind of defeats the purpose of using SourceTree in the first place).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently updated to SourceTree 3.3.6 on Windows and the whitespace is now visible in the diff. There is a new option in `Tools > Options > Diff > Show whitespace characters using the following symbol` if you want to change it to something other than the dot.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To see tabs differently than spaces, you need to disable the option `Tools -> Options -> Diff -> Convert tabs to spaces with width:`. In such a situation tabs mangle display of whitespace, and the tab size is fixed to something about 6.7 (including diff markers).

That's how it looks like (below the same file in Notepad++ for reference):

[image: Sourcetree 3.3.4 above, Notepad++ 7.8.5 below]